# C# returning week as a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am making a switch case for a method that takes a string mnemonic and returns a DateTime as a result.
For example this is part of it:

```
switch (mnemonic)
{
    case CURRENT_TIME:
        return DateTime.Now;
    case TODAY:
        return DateTime.Now.Date;
}
```

The issue I'm stuck with is the case for:

```
case THIS_WEEK:
```

How do you return what week it is as a DateTime object?

Comment: `DateTime.Today` is neater

Comment: A week is a span of time, so it wouldn't apply, but you could test for the start day of the week, but that depends on what day you consider to be the start of the week, which is arguable and varies regionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a week is defined by two points, a start date and an end date. If you want to return just one datetime object then return the starting date and you have the knowledge that a week covers 7 days from the starting date.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the week by simple math

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
DayOfWeek firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

var firstDayOfTheWeek = date.AddDays(firstDay - date.DayOfWeek);
Console.WriteLine(firstDayOfTheWeek);

int weekNumber = firstDayOfTheWeek.DayOfYear / 7; // In case you want this information as well.
Console.WriteLine(weekNumber);
```

Comment: Not all cultures end the week on the same day.

Comment: Probably better to parameterize the start day of the week, rather than the hardcoded Sunday, as it's not globally consistent. Many people treat Monday as the start of the week. Rightly so, I would say :-p

Comment: @stuartd, I believe the OP can do the culture himself, it's just a small addition to the code.

Comment: @OrelEraki "it's just a small addition to the code" implies "this does not actually answer the question". You didn't mention cultural differences in your answer, either.

Comment: @stuartd, You are right about the culture differences, and was fixed accordingly.

Comment: If `date.DayOfWeek` is less than `firstDay`, you will actually be adding days and thus get the first day of the **next** week! I would subtract 7 from the difference in that case. You should always add 0 or a negative number.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

```
Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()
```

See this: [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear Method (DateTime, CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)

This code will provide you with the week # for the current date you are looking at.  If you want to display the first day of the week then you could calculate that DateTime object from this information.  However, I would make a DateTime wrapper class that also includes the week # if that is the item you are specifically looking for and return that.

Comment: So in this case "technically correct" means "returning a different datatype altogether from the requirement"?

Comment: Updated my suggestion because you are right, I didn't address the question.  I, instead, am providing an alternative solution.